# couldn't show flowchart with two libraries pstricks and tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

I was trying to add some flowcharts to my Article, but I had some issues with that, with this code:

```
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node}
    \begin{center}
      \begin{psmatrix}
        & [name=nodo1,mnode=circle] Nodo 1 \\
        & [name=nodo2,mnode=circle] Nodo 2 \\
        \ncline{->}{nodo1}{nodo2}
      \end{psmatrix}
    \end{center}
```

It must show something like that [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uhLV.png):

[[image: FLOWCHART]]

But when I add to my code it shows this [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pf90s.png):

[[image: Wrong code]]

I used those dependences

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{robotlabs}

% Makes tables look nicer
\usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

% To change size of verbatim
\usepackage{verbatimbox}

%Insert code



\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind} %Incluir numeracion de biblio en tabla de contenido
\definecolor{Pink}{rgb}{1.,0.75,0.8}
\include{commands}
\include{labutils}
```

As well I try to use `tikz` but I had the same problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Thanks, @Mensch 
`\c@lor@to@ps ->\PSTricks 
                         _Not_Configured_For_This_Format
l.5     & [name=nodo1,mnode=circle] Nodo 1 \\`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: two simple nodes on a path]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle,draw}]
        \path node (N1) {Nodo 1} --++ (0,-3) node (N2) {Nodo 2};
        \draw[-stealth] (N1) -- (N2);   
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can still play with styles, then.

Comment: Thanks, very useful!

Answer (score 5):

This simplified code compiles fine with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
      \begin{psmatrix}[mnode=circle]
        & [name=nodo1] Nodo 1 \\
        & [name=nodo2] Nodo 2
        \ncline{->}{nodo1}{nodo2}
      \end{psmatrix}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]